# symbolic link new target

Tags: symlink

I want to change the symbolic links pointing to the current directory, to a common directory named /pool

current directory  a/b
common directory   a/pool

I followed every I could find and came close with this script.

```
#!/bin/sh
from="$1"
to="$2"
shift 2
for i
do
  a=$(readlink "$i") && ln -sf "$(echo $a | sed "s@$from@$to@")" "$i"
done
```

before running the script ...

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neysa neysa  18 Jan  4 22:03 xfsm-logout.png -> system-log-out.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neysa neysa  17 Jan  4 22:03 zoom-best-fit.png -> zoom-fit-best.png
```

after running the script
    ./rename-links . ../pool/

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neysa neysa  25 Jan  4 22:31 xfsm-logout.png -> ../pool/ystem-log-out.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neysa neysa  24 Jan  4 22:31 zoom-best-fit.png -> ../pool/oom-fit-best.png
```

it's working but with one fault, missing the first letter of the target.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`.` [is a regular expression metacharacter in `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions), which matches any single character. Because you just insert the `$from` path into the regular expression directly, the `.` is there as though you'd written:

```
sed "s@.@../pool/@"
```

yourself. That [replaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) any single character, once, with "`../pool/`", so it has the effect of deleting the first character and inserting "../pool/" in its place.

If you run the `readlink` command manually you'll find that `./` is not a part of the link contents — your `ls` shows the same.

You will at the least need to special-case "`.`" in your script, since it may or may not be present in the link contents. One option is to use [`readlink -f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) on both the link and `.` — which will give you absolute paths to both — but there are simpler options if you only have the single case to deal with.

---

If you're in `bash` you can get away without `sed` at all [using basic parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-expansion_002c-parameter):

```
ln -sf "${a/$from/$to}" "$i"
```

That will replace the expansion of `$from` with the expansion of `$to` in `$a`, with`.` treated literally (although `*` and other *shell* metacharacters are used - really it should be `"${a/"$from"/"$to"}"` to avoid that). This is a cleaner and simpler way of doing it overall.

Comment: Since I am working on icon sets I want all the symlinks in different size folders to point to a common directory which will hold icons in svg format. ( earlier it was in PNG format , hence different size folders with symlinks pointing to same directory) to correct every link manually will be tough since I need a simple script to do it

Comment: just added -f after readlink in the script as Mr.Michael Homer suggested and staying in the links directory issued command as                                           bash ../rename-links /home/***/links/ ../pool/ *                                                     and it worked, it just added ../pool/ in front to the symlinks without deleting any character. Thankyou.